# sort the announcement in SharePoint news webpart

Tags: office-365

I'm using SharePoint announcement webpart to show announcements from across the sites. This shows the latest announcement on top. Is there a way to specify the order in which the announcement are shown?

I tried checking the webpart properties, but it only has options to change layouts/ sites  and other options mentioned here [Use the News web part on a SharePoint page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-the-News-web-part-on-a-SharePoint-page-C2DCEE50-F5D7-434B-8CB9-A7FEEFD9F165)

Answer (score 0):

If the webpart doesn't support what you are looking for, you could opt for the content search webpart (if in a classic site).

See https://www.sharepointeurope.com/displaying-corporate-news-with-the-content-search-webpart/ for an example.